# passing data between controllers shows an error

Tags: ios, swift3

I've put a navigation controller in between viewcontrollers according to my project. When I tried to pass the data its shows the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x10900b008) to 'uday.Food_Drinks_DetailTableViewController' (0x105b72600).
```

This is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "fdShow", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "fdShow"{
        if let indexpath = tablevi.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let fddVc = segue.destination as! Food_Drinks_DetailTableViewController

            fddVc.FdString = fad[indexpath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error at the following line:

```
let fddVc = segue.destination as! Food_Drinks_DetailTableViewController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your segue destination is UINavigationController.If you are not using custom class for navigation controller. You need to change code to

```
let navVc = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
```

and then, if Food_Drinks_DetailTableViewController is the first controller in navigation controller

```
let fddVc = navVc.viewControllers.first as! Food_Drinks_DetailTableViewController
 fddVc.FdString = fad[indexpath.row]
```

Comment: : Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'FdString'